# setting up django & celery: location for celery path

Tags: django

I'm setting up celery based on an example and at this point...

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/webapps/hello_django/hello:$PYTHONPATH
$ /webapps/hello_django/bin/celery --app=hello.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

on my end set as

```
 samuel@samuel-pc:~/Documents/code/revamp$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery:$PYTHONPATH
 samuel@samuel-pc:~/Documents/code/revamp$ /home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/revamp/celery --app=revamp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
 bash: /home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/revamp/celery: No such file or directory
```

not sure what it did to the path and this is what the result should be

```
 -------------- celery@django v3.1.11 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.2.0-4-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-7.5
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         hello_django:0x15ae410
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

[tasks]
  . testapp.tasks.test

[2014-05-20 13:53:59,740: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2014-05-20 13:53:59,748: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-05-20 13:54:00,756: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2014-05-20 13:54:00,769: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@django ready.
```

my guess is I need to set path to the path for celery installation, if so anyone who can tell me the path.

Comment: Have you installed celery? Why do you think it should be at `/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/revamp/celery` ?

Answer (score 0):

Had lots of headeaches with celery tutorials out there. Try this:

- First thing you need a [virtual enviroment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for your project, so you dont need to setup paths.

bash:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

- Then you need a django project and an app.

bash:

```
   pip install django
   django-admin starproject myproject
   cd myproject
   python manage.py startapp myapp
```

- Then you should `pip install celery`
- Next make a tasks.py on the same level of your view.py on myapp directory:

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.decorators import task

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@task(bind=True,name="my_task")    
def my_task(self):
   print('hello')
   return 1+1
```

- Install your broker (rabbitmq)

bash:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

- Go to your app directory, the one that has tasks.py and run `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`. This only works on the directory that tasks is defined. Then you should have your worker up and runnning. When you print or return something from your task it should appear here.
- Finally you should use your task. Setup a view(setup url, make a template, etc.) and call your task from the view:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .tasks import my_task

def index(request):
    my_task.delay()
    return render({},'index.html')
```

The magic is that the delay call is assync, non-blockable.
From this minimalistic example I hope you can understand better the paths you tutorials talk about and do complicated stuff that they make you do: like placing celery settings on settings.py, calling the worker from other directories, putting things on path...   This was a real pain when I was trying to learn this from the oficial docs.

Good luck!

Comment: you know what I'll try rabbitmq instead of redis... see if I can get further on.

Comment: The error you described is f ixed by virtualenv, not rabbitmq